# Get name without version numbers with javascript

Tags: javascript

for example "program example v1.2" and "program example V2.5" i want to take only the name "program example" with javascript function. how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Looks like a simple regular expression matching problem

Comment: Is the "name" of `"program example V2.5"` a string in a variable somewhere?

Comment: tried google search :D

Comment: i want to substring only "program example" with a function on both examples

Comment: like getName('program example v1.2')  to return "'program example";
like getName('program example v2.5')  to return "'program example";

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, what you're asking for is basic string manipulation and there are several ways to accomplish what you want, each with their own foibles and trade-offs. Here are a couple of ways to do it:

```js
const tests = [
    'program example v1.2',
    'program example V2.5',
    'some program v1.3',
    'some other program v7.9',
    'yet another thing v12.1',
    'the bestest ever app v0.1',
];

const methodUsingRegex = (s) => {
    return s.replace(/\s+[vV]\d+.*$/, '');
};

/*
 *    regex works as follows:
 *
 * \s+  <- look for whitespace
 * [vV] <- followed by a V (case-insensitive)
 * \d+  <- followed by a digit
 * .*   <- followed by anything whatsoever
 * $    <- until the end of the string
 *
 * this of course will break if any input string
 * doesn't exactly match this pattern, i.e.,
 *     'some executable version 3'
 *     or
 *     'some other executable v 1.5'
 *     or
 *     'yet another executable ver 9.3'
 */

const methodUsingArrayMethods = (s) => {
    const parts = s.split(' ');
    parts.pop();    // remove last element of array
    return parts.join(' ');
};

/*
 * relies on a space between the program name
 * and the version and number.
 * further relies on the version and number
 * being the last space-delimited info chunk
 * in the string.
 *
 * easily breaks if any of that is not met, i.e.,
 *     'some executable version 3'          // would return 'some executable version'
 *     or
 *     'some other executable v 1.5'        // would return 'some other executable v'
 *     or
 *     'yet another executable ver 9.3'     // would return 'yet another executable ver'
 */

console.log(tests.map(methodUsingRegex));
console.log(tests.map(methodUsingArrayMethods));
```

The above is in ES6 syntax, but since I don't know your project requirements, here's the same thing in ES5:

```js
var tests = [
    'program example v1.2',
    'program example V2.5',
    'some program v1.3',
    'some other program v7.9',
    'yet another thing v12.1',
    'the bestest ever app v0.1',
];

var methodUsingRegex = function (s) {
    return s.replace(/\s+[vV]\d+.*$/, '');
};

var methodUsingArrayMethods = function (s) {
    const parts = s.split(' ');
    parts.pop();    // remove last element of array
    return parts.join(' ');
};

console.log(tests.map(methodUsingRegex));
console.log(tests.map(methodUsingArrayMethods));
```

If you could share some code you've tried and some sample data, you could get a better answer.